# Getting an Error while using AverageIFS Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average

I have been receiving an error while using AverageIFS function the error is Evaluation of function AVERAGEIFS caused a divide by zero error.

I am matching 4 columns where it gives error but when use for three it works fine.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A,D3,Sheet1!$B:$B,$A$2,Sheet1!$D:$D,$B$2,Sheet1!$D:$D,$B$3)
```

[Link to Sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18_IwYvdZsZWkDJ7zuofnu8-KjrdmddVhUEIZz5-MBo0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your link has disappeared so we can't see the problem or solution in context anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell G2 of Sheet 2 I entered

```
=query(Sheet1!A:D, "Select A, avg(C) where B ='"&A2&"' and D matches '"&textjoin("|", true, B2:B3)&"' group by A label avg(C) 'Average'", 1)
```

As an alternative for your current solution you can try

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A=D3,Sheet1!$B:$B=$A$2,( (Sheet1!$D:$D=$B$2) + (Sheet1!$D:$D=$B$3))))
```

and drag down.

The current solution does not work because there are no rows where all conditions are met. E.g: Column D can't contain 'PAF' *and* 'PAN'.

See if that works for you?